# SQL Trigger calculating difference for timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, timestamp

I cannot seem to find a solution on calculating time difference, using trigger for automatically generating duration into my table when inserting two timestamps.

Here is my table 'call':

```
create table call(
    id varchar(5),
    start_time timestamp,
    end_time timestamp,
    duration INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND (4),
    primary key(id));
```

I am trying to use a trigger

```
create sequence time_diff;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DURATION 
BEFORE INSERT ON call
for each row
BEGIN
begin select time_diff //confused and don't know what to do
END;
```

I am hoping doing insertion like this would work

```
insert into call values(111,'2015-04-21 15:42:23','2016-11-03 18:32:47',null);
```

and my timestamp format is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things: First, why are you storing a calculated number? Violating normal form. At the very least, make it a  virtual column. Second, you can't enter timestamps like that; use the proper syntax for timestamps. (If you don't know what it is, type "Oracle timestamp literal" in Google.) Third, is your question how to compute the difference between two timestamps, in seconds? The difference between timestamps is an "interval day to second"; you can extract day, hour, minute and second from it (separately), and convert everything to seconds. As in, `tsdiff := timestamp_1 - timestamp_2`, and then `diff_seconds := extract (day from tsdiff) * 86400 + extract(hour from tsdiff) * 3600 + ...`

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! So if I am gonna make a virtual column, do you mean the type should be "interval"? And I don't understand why I can't enter timestamp like that. I can insert that kind of timestamp into my other table.

Comment: Sorry, actually I take it back about timestamp literals. I missed the last line in your post; I guess what you mean is that your NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT parameter is what you showed, and then you should be fine. Regarding the difference: the type can be interval day to second (you can Google to find the full syntax, including precision) - unless you really need it all expressed in seconds. Good luck!